# JSON structure PHP - strange

Tags: php, arrays, json

Im working with Google tag Manager API(v2), and trying to add some new lines to my existing JSON array. I first had some trouble adding data to my JSON object because the data was shown on the last row and not inside the object itself.

Now ive changed my code but the data does not look like its inside the object itself but im a little bit closer now. This is how my JSON object looks like now:

**JSON:**

```
{
    "Account2": [{
        "accountId": "17467*****",
        "containerId": "745****",
    }, 3, 3, 4, {
        "accountId": "17467*****",
        "containerId": "751****",
    }, 1, 1, 2],
    "Account 1": [{
        "accountId": "17661*****",
        "containerId": "748****",
    }, 2, 1, 1],
    "GTMdocx": [{
        "accountId": "21200*****",
        "containerId": "803****",
    }, 0, 0, 1],
    "Account3": [{
        "accountId": "21281*****",
        "containerId": "803****",
    }, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

As you can see the object is structured like this:
1) Accountname
2) Inside `Accountname` we have `accountId` and `containerId`
3) at last of one Accountname object we have some numbers(count), the problem is that it looks like this:
[image]

**What i would want** the JSON-object to look like is like this:

```
{
    "Account2": [{
        "accountId": "17467*****",
        "containerId": "745****",
        "tags": "3",
        "triggers": "3",
        "variables": "4"

    }, {
        "accountId": "17467*****",
        "containerId": "751****",
        "tags": "3",
        "triggers": "3",
        "variables": "4"
    }],
    "Account 1": [{
        "accountId": "17661*****",
        "containerId": "748****",
        "tags": "2",
        "triggers": "1",
        "variables": "1"
    }],
    "GTMdocx": [{
        "accountId": "21200*****",
        "containerId": "803****",
        "tags": "0",
        "triggers": "0",
        "variables": "1"
    }],
    "Account3": [{
        "accountId": "21281*****",
        "containerId": "803****",
        "tags": "0",
        "triggers": "0",
        "variables": "0"
    }]
}
```

You can see the numbers got a key and then value inside the object.

**This is my PHP-code:**

```
static public function listAllContainers() {

    try { //Because some containers might not have live-version
        $containers[] = array();
        foreach (self::listAccounts()->account as $accountKey => $account) {
            foreach (self::listAccountsContainers($account["path"]) as $account_container) {
                $containers[$account['name']][] = $account_container;

                $container_version = self::listAccountsContainersVersion($account_container['path']);
                $containers[$account['name']][] = count($container_version['tag']);
                $containers[$account['name']][] = count($container_version['trigger']);
                $containers[$account['name']][] = count($container_version['variable']);


            }
        }
        $filtered_array = (object)array_filter((array)$containers); // Removes empty object
        return $filtered_array;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getCode();
    }
}
```

Hope you understand my problem. Not so much experience with Arrays/JSON so maybe my explanation is not so good.
Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Using `$containers[$account['name']]['tag'] = count($container_version['tag']);` gives me this JSON: (PS: ive removed some from the json so it wont be long, this makes the json invalid)

```
{
Account2: {
0: {
accountId: "174675****",
containerId: "745****",
},
1: {
accountId: "174675****59",
containerId: "751****83",
},
tag: 1,
trigger: 1,
variable: 2
},
Account 1: {
0: {
accountId: "1766***525",
containerId: "748***53",
},
tag: 2,
trigger: 1,
variable: 1
},
```

Now each "Account" can have multiple "containers"(accountId,containerId), using this method does not store the data inside the object itself.

Comment: Why downvote? did i break some rules?

Comment: Well you can simply give it a name like this `$containers[$account['name']]['tag'] = count($container_version['tag']);` (see the first 'tag') or put it inside your `$account_container` array like `$account_container['tag'] = ...`.

Comment: @xander '$containers[$account['name']]['tag'] = count($container_version['tag']);' is giving me not the object inside "account1". if you can see what i want is it to come under "containerId" not an own object iself. See updated answer to illustrate

Comment: It was just an example, I gave you another one that is more like the answer from @user3053216 below, that should work better with what you want.

Comment: Using @user305... solution does not show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array, you can add a key:value pair to it with the following syntax:

```
$array['key'] = 'value';
//array('key' : 'value')
```

If you don't specify a key, it will just add the value:

```
$array[] = 'value';
//array('value')
```

The last part is what you are doing now, but you add it to your $containers[...] array. What you want to do is add the values first to your $account_container array, and then add that array to your $containers[...] array. Put this in the inner foreach:

```
        $container_version = self::listAccountsContainersVersion($account_container['path']);

        //Add values to account_container
        $account_container['tag'] = count($container_version['tag']);
        $account_container['trigger'] = count($container_version['trigger']);
        $account_container['variable'] = count($container_version['variable']);

        // Add account_container to your $containers[..] array
        $containers[$account['name']][] = $account_container;
```

Comment: Ive tried to use this code but the "tag","trigger","variable" count does not show in the JSON?

Comment: @Asim In your original code you do `$containers[$account['name']][] = $account_container;` so you add the container to your JSON, so if you add some values to the `$account_container` it should work. Maybe there is some other error or weird logic happening behind the scenes of your code!?

Comment: Yes reading this code should do work. Very strange. It works, but just a minor problem that if   1account has 3containers all 3 containers gets identical count numbers wich is wrong. But on "account"-level it works perfect, just not on "containers"-level in JSON block

Comment: That sounds like you have a reference to your account container instead of a single object for each a reference is reused by some other code, hard to say without seeing all the code. What you can do is use a debugger to step by step through the code to see what is actually happening in your loop. So solve this you can use a new temp array instead of extending `$account_container` and merge it together with `array_merge`. It's not that hard if you know some array basics in PHP. :)

Comment: Ill try that and come back. Hope you can help me if i encounter problems with this procedure. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Asim Sure it's hard to help with real code in the comments, that's why I added another answer with some changes that might work better.

Answer (score 0):

I put together another solution without modifying the original `$account_container`.

I've added the new data in a new array `$account_container_extra` and merged that together with `$account_container` when appending it to the `$container` array.

Maybe that will work better for you or give you some other ideas.

```
static public function listAllContainers() {

    try { //Because some containers might not have live-version
        $containers[] = array();
        foreach (self::listAccounts()->account as $accountKey => $account) {
            foreach (self::listAccountsContainers($account["path"]) as $account_container) {
                $container_version = self::listAccountsContainersVersion($account_container['path']);

                $account_container_extra = [
                    'tag' => count($container_version['tag']),
                    'trigger' => count($container_version['trigger']),
                    'variable' => count($container_version['variable'])
                ];

                $containers[$account['name']][] = array_merge($account_container, $account_container_extra);
            }
        }
        $filtered_array = (object)array_filter((array)$containers); // Removes empty object
        return $filtered_array;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in (...) :(

Comment: Ill try to make a jsfiddle

Comment: Maybe your `$account_container` is not an array, but a class object? I don't think jsfiddle will work for your PHP project. You can either convert the class to an array or extract the class members you need and build an array from that. That information was not visible in your original question, it's much easier if you know your other code and how it works together of course, but I'm assuming you have not written that code?

Comment: This was written by me @xander, what other code you need? '$account_container' is an object not array sir

Comment: Well if you have written all that code yourself you should have some ideas on how to solve that warning. You know writing code in a text field on this site is a lot harder than experimenting with your own code and testing some stuff and actually see the result in front of you :)